# MySQL Query works in phpmyadmin but not in node

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I have a query with LEFT joins which works fine in phpmyadmin but same query returns null for certain rows in node server. I am new to both node and MySQL.

Here is my query to fetch highest selling category between a date range:

```
SELECT o.order_id,c.category_id,c.category_name as Name, o.book_id, o.date_of_purchase, SUM(o.quantity) as Total, o.payment_method 
FROM `order_details` as o 
LEFT JOIN book as b on b.book_id = o.book_id
LEFT JOIN category as c on c.category_id = b.book_id
 GROUP BY c.category_id 
 ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 1
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Here are my table and query result:

[image]

Result of the same in node is :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "order_id": 20,
            "category_id": null,
            "Name": null,
            "book_id": 6,
            "date_of_purchase": "2017-07-23T13:22:37.000Z",
            "Total": 55,
            "payment_method": "NB"
        }
    ],
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success"
}
```

Node code where I call the query:

/* Get highest selling category */

```
category.getHighestSelling = function(fromDate, toDate) {

    var query = "SELECT min(o.order_id) , c.category_id  , c.category_name as Name  , o.book_id  , min(o.date_of_purchase)  , SUM(o.quantity) as Total  , min(o.payment_method) " +
        "FROM `order_details` as o " +
        "LEFT JOIN book as b on b.book_id = o.book_id " +
        "LEFT JOIN category as c on c.category_id = b.book_id " +
        "GROUP BY c.category_id , o.book_id " +
        "ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 1 ";
    if (fromDate && toDate) {
        query += "WHERE `date_of_purchase` BETWEEN '" + dateFormat(fromDate, "yyyy-mm-dd , h:MM:ss ") + "' AND '" + (dateFormat(toDate, "yyyy-mm-dd , h:MM:ss ") || new Date()) + "'";
    }
    return utilities.executeQuery(query);
};
```

Comment: Where is your code for Node? That might help

Comment: How can your `category_id` = `book_id`? That doesn't seem like the logical relationship between the 2 tables.

Comment: @WEI_DBA : You are right it should have been category.category_id = book.category_id. eeegh, how did i miss this. But that is not the problem.. I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @jakerella : i have a function which executes this query. I have added it to my question now.

Comment: before return you can console.log(query); to be sure, it is identical. The optional where clause is not the same as your query above...